# Laravel Cron Job not running over ubuntu server

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, cron, jobs

I have a laravel application setup over Ubuntu server using Nginx. Here I have the cron jobs. I was facing an issue, that the server was not automatically picking up changes on Jobs Files. So I googled the things, and found a command from this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/call-to-undefined-function-app-jobs-curl_init-in-laravel-job-using-do-lamp-droplet) which I ran;

```
 php artisan queue:restart
```

Since I have run this command, now no job is running even. I am also trying with simple HeartbeatJob to log info but it is also not working. When I do `php artisan schedule:run`,
no error in particular just screen output as:

```
[2021-09-11T08:41:32+00:00] Running scheduled command: App\Jobs\Heartbeat
```

But nothing happens. Any idea what this queue command has done wrong and how I make my jobs working again?

Comment: Can you post your cron job?

Answer (score 0):

Your cron job will need the absolute path to artisan, so should look something like :

```
php /home/user/site.com/artisan queue:restart
```

You may also need to specify the queue with :

```
php /home/user/site.com/artisan queue:restart --queue=nameofqueue
```

Comment: I don't think `php artisan queue:restart` is inside a cron job. OP ran it via CLI to restart the queue

Comment: @brombeer can you explain further?

Comment: What is was saying is that you probably ran `php artisan queue:restart` in a terminal and _not_ as a cronjob.

Comment: @brombeer - true, however he does mention that he is using cron jobs, so that may be at least part of the issue. 

Specifying the queue name when restarting from the CLI in any event, if it's not "default", is required, I think.

Comment: @GilesBennett issue is; nothing is getting execute even when I do PHP artisan schedule:run